# Haskell - declare/use data

Tags: haskell, types

It's my first time to use data types in Haskell.
Got a problem and I don't know how to improve the code.

Here is the problem:

Declear a data type called "Consonant" which include some letters(string), and an textstring which got the information about if all the letters in that word are consonant or not (string), then write a function "Cheak" which got indata (some letters to cheak) and outdata (the data type "Consonant").

Here is my code:

```
module Consonant where

import Char

type Name = String
type ConOrNot = String
data Consonant = Cons Name ConOrNot
    deriving (Show,Eq)


isVowel = "AEIOU"

cheak :: String -> Consonant

cheak [] = ""
cheak (char:chars) =
if  elem (toUpper char) isVowel  == false
then    cheak chars
else    cheak = Cons (char:chars) "Not Consonant"   
-- here I want to use "break", but I don't know how to use it in Haskell...  

cheak = Cons (char:chars) "Is Consonant"
```

It doesn't work... How to change the code?  Pls help! Thank you!

Update:

```
   module Consonant where

   import Char

   type Word = String
   type ConOrNot = String
   data Consonant = Cons Word ConOrNot
       deriving (Show,Eq)


   isConsonant = "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ"

   cheak :: String -> Consonant

   cheak [] = Cons "" ""


   cheak (char:chars) 
       |elem (toUpper char) isCosonant = cheak chars  --if all the letters are cosonant, I want it return (Cons (char:chars) "is Consonant").. still working on it
       |otherwise              = Cons (char:chars) "Not Consonant"
```

It works now if the string got both vowels and consonant or only vowels, how to improve the code so it also works with only consonants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking for.  Is the `Word` in the returned `Cons` supposed to be the `Word` passed to `cheak` or the remainder of the `Word` starting from the first vowel?

Does this do what you want?

```
module Consonant
    where

import Data.Char

type Word = String
type ConOrNot = String
data Consonant = Cons Word ConOrNot
                 deriving (Show,Eq)

cheak :: Word -> Consonant
cheak "" = Cons "" ""
cheak s = Cons s $ if any isVowel s then "Not Consonant" else "is Consonant"
          where isVowel c = (toUpper c) `elem` "AEIOU"
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5):

This is homework, isn't it?

Issues with your code include:

1. This line makes no sense:

   ```
   cheak [] = ""
   ```

   because `cheak` is supposed to return a `Consonant`, but here you return a `String`.
2. This line also makes no sense:

   ```
   cheak = Cons (seq:seqs) "Is Consonant"
   ```

   beacause `cheak` is supposed to take a `String` parameter and return a `Consonant`, but here you just return a `Consonant` without taking any parameter.
3. This line makes even less sense:

   ```
   else    cheak = Cons (seq:seqs) "Not Consonant"
   ```

   Haskell is not Pascal or Visual Basic. You return a value from a function by letting the RHS of the equation evaluate to that value.
4. Indentation matters.
5. There is a function called `break` in Haskell, but it is unrelated to the `break` keyword you may be familiar with from Java or C. The Java/C concept of breaking out of a loop doesn't exist in Haskell.
6. You probably want to use a helper function.
7. "Cheak" isn't a word.
8. `if`-`then`-`else` is not a statement. The then-branch and the else-branch are not statements either. They're all expressions. It's like `?:` from Java, C and some other languages.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do what you want to do in Haskell. The obvious first choices are Maybe and Either. But in general, checkout the [8 ways to report errors in Haskell](http://www.randomhacks.net/articles/2007/03/10/haskell-8-ways-to-report-errors) .